# Custom sort in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, polynomials

I have a structure which represents a monomial like this:

```
    (M coefficient monomial-degree vars)
```

So the following monomial 3 * x * y^2 should be represented like this:

```
    (M 3 3 ((V 1 X) (V 2 Y)))
```

Now, I have a list of monomials with this kind of structure, so for example:

```
    ((M 3 3 ((V 1 X) (V 2 Y))) (M 2 1 ((V 1 X))))
```

What I am trying to do is sort the list of monomials with the following rules:
1-sort monomials firstly by incresing monomial-degree

2-if two monomials have the same monomial-degree, sort them by their variables. Which means firstly considering their variables and sort them with an alphabetical order, if they have the same variables, I should sort them by considering their variables degree and sort them with an incresing order.

So considering the example represented above the result should be:

```
    ((M 2 1 ((V 1 X))) (M 3 3 ((V 1 X) (V 2 Y))))
```

Now let's consider three monomials with the same variables/degree:

```
    ((M 2 2 ((V 1 A) (V 1 C))) (M 3 2 ((V 2 A))) (M 1 2 ((V 1 A) (V 1 B))))
```

The result should be:

```
    ((M 1 2 ((V 1 A) (V 1 B))) (M 2 2 ((V 1 A) (V 1 C))) (M 3 2 ((V 1 A))))
```

So in the first case I use a sort function like this to sort by monomial-degree:

```
    (sort (copy-seq lista) #'<  :key #'third)
```

But im not really sure how to sort if monomials have the same monomial-degree.
I thought about a custom sort function but I'm not sure on how should I implement it.

Comment: This looks very similiar to an [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41077682/5747548). Have you looked at the answer to it?

Comment: First of all: look at the (my) answer to the previous question jkiiski mentions, and use some abstraction.  Secondly, you need to define a function which compares two monomials according to the rules you want to use.  Then use `sort`.